# How to synchronously execute java script lines without setting time delay manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

In my ajax success section i have to reload my grid and after that i have to set grid focus to next cell, these are
created as  two functions, while i calling these functions, due to taking more time to reload grid the second function is not working properly.
How can i execute my second function only after first function execution complete without setting any time delay
(while using set Timeout it is working but i want to remove the manual time setting)

```
function myFirstFunction() { 
$('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); 
} 
function mySecondFunction() { 
//some codes, should only execute after above grid reload completed
 }
```

Comment: function myFirstFunction()
{
 -----
 -----
 $('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
}

function mySecondFunction()
{
 //some codes, should only execute after above grid reload completed
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.then()`

```
function myFirstFunction() { 
$('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read().then(function() {
mySecondFunction();
}); 
} 
function mySecondFunction() { 
//some codes, should only execute after above grid reload completed
 }
```

[Kendo Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFirstFunction() { 
$('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); 
} 
async function mySecondFunction() { 
//some codes, should only execute after above grid reload completed
const result = await myFirstFunction();
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem here?

Comment: async keyword is not working for me... may be javascript version problem..i am using kendo 2018 jquery..can you suggest 'async' supporting version

Comment: Depends on the browser you are using. For example, async/await and Promises are not working with Internet Explorer. If you want to use it in Internet Explorer or older browsers, you have to use Polyfills.

Comment: Also if you want to use async/await you have to return the promise of `read()` in `myFirstFunction()`. Change `function myFirstFunction() { 
$('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); 
} ` to `function myFirstFunction() { 
return $('#grdMySampleGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read(); 
} `

Comment: getting build error not debug error (keyword not supporting), i am using chrome as browser  Version 76.0.3809.132